# All permissions with declarative_authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I have a Rails application using Restful authentication and declarative authorization. I have some roles with an admin.

Is there any method to have automatically granted all permissions to this role, instead of hardcode every controller in the authorization_rules? Something like:

```
role :admin do 
  has_permission_on :everything, :to => :manage
end
```

Or a uglier approach with introspection, maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this if you use the latest code (the latest gem (0.4.1) still doesn't have it):

```
role :admin do
  has_omnipotence
end
```

With that the admin role would have all permissions on all models.

See the commit: [4ecb402f](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/commit/4ecb402f1c7b24855db57933bfc5741d30c66a8f)

Comment: By any chance Tomas, do you think you could take a look at the issue I am having with decl_auth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631218/how-do-i-access-a-user-with-a-specific-role-in-rails-3   Thanks.