# How do I access a user with a specific role in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models for users. User, role & assignments. This is how the models look:

```
    assignment.rb

# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101117094659
#
# Table name: assignments
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  user_id    :integer
#  role_id    :integer
#

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :user
end

role.rb

# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101117094659
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end

user.rb

# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110102225945
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         primary key
#  email                :string(255)
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)
#  password_salt        :string(255)
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  username             :string(255)
#  f_name               :string(255)
#  l_name               :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, and :lockable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :stages
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end  
end
```

In my view, to select the projects for the current user, I do this:

In my projects controller, I have:

```
def index
@projects = current_user.projects

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @projects }
end
```

end

Then in the view I do this:

```
<% if current_user.projects.exists? %>
                    <div class="data">
                        There are <%= current_user.projects.count %> projects.<br />
                        <table>
                            <% current_user.projects.each do |project| %>
                                <tr class="changer">
                                    <td><%= link_to project.name, project %></td>
                                </tr>
                            <% end %>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                <% else %>
                    <div class="no-data">
                        <%= image_tag('create-project-icon.png') %><br />
                        Create Project
                    </div>      
                <% end %>
```

The users have 4 roles: Designer, Client, Admin, Superuser.

Each designer can have multiple clients. Each client can also belong to multiple designers.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. If the currently logged in user (a designer) wants to add a client (they can only add clients, no other user type), how do I do that? What's the syntax I will use according to my code samples above. Once I add a client, I will want to associate him to projects, stages, uploads and comments. So in theory, 1 designer will have multiple projects which will belong to multiple clients.
2. How do I then retrieve the clients only, for the designer logged in. i.e. how do I select all the users with role client associated with the current_user ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how do you restrict it so that a Designer can only add a Client? I think you are using declarative_authorization from a comment on another question but that is not clear from this question. Also there doesn't appear to be an association between users that would allow you to add a user as a client of a designed unless that is through other unspecified associations. It might just be me but I don't feel like there's enough clarity here to answer the question.

Comment: As of right Shadwell, there are no more unspecified associations. I am trying to figure out how to progress. Well, that question about the designer only adding a client is a very good one. I was working under the assumption that anybody that the designer adds (i.e. any user) will always have the role 'client'. But no, that was not the question. The question was...given that users (clients) have already been added to a project owned by another user (a designer), how do I retrieve those users.

Comment: So the idea is, I have project A with 4 users with role client. How do I do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 'client' & Project = 'A'`? Without doing any SQL statements. Ideally, I would only use Ruby/Rails code. I am using decl_auth & devise for authentication. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> The question was...given that users (clients) have already been added
>   to a project owned by another user (a designer), how do I retrieve
>   those users

That is pretty straight forward :

```
# Given a project @project = Project.find(id)
@clients = @project.users.joins(:roles).where("roles.name = 'client'")
```